# How can I make a surface reflective enough for a solar grill?

Tags: paint, product-recommendation

I am working to build a solar grill.  This requires making a reflective surface.  Is there a good paint option for, say, cardboard or plastic that is very reflective?  When I google "reflective paint" all I get is retro-reflective paint for nighttime visibility.  If I google "mirror paint" I get paint that goes on glass.  It doesn't need to be optical quality.... just need to reflect as much incident light as possible.

Which means can I employ to make surfaces reflect the maximum amount of sunlight?

Comment: A high-gloss paint will be the most reflective, matte least and the other sheens somewhere inbetween. You may find one that is aluminized that would be more reflective, but I think you'll be very dissappointed in the reflectivity of paint for this purpose. You'd probably be better of going with highly polished metal. There's a reason that solar furnaces actually use glass mirrors. Maybe a search for "make a solar furnace" might get you some better resources...

Comment: Searching google for "Mirror *Finish* Paint" brings up some pretty good results... Rustoleum has a "mirror effect" spray paint. Note though that to get a good mirror effect, the surface you are painting must be extremely smooth. Cardboard probably won't fit the bill here, plastic might work but may have adhesion issues. Ideally you'd get a piece of aluminum plate and paint that...

Comment: How large a collection area do you have in mind? I'm hard pressed to see how you could shape cardboard into anything vaguely parabolic (or spherical).    In any case, paint will NEVER work -- too diffuse, even "mirror paints."   You need to look into getting a properly shaped plastic or metal base and coating with actual metal via vapor dep or some such process.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I don't need to focus the light into a point, just into a smaller area.  For example, a flat mirror could be positioned to reflect light into a container of approximately the same size.  Several such mirrors could make a decent solar collector for cooking purposes.  [For example](https://www.nbcnews.com/id/wbna39403349)

Comment: I've revised your post to be less of a shopping/[XY](http://xyproblem.info) question. Hopefully this gets you more usable advice and avoids closure.

Comment: Also, you may want to consider the results when the _Mythbusters_ tested out the [Archimedes Death Ray](https://go.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/full-episodes/archimedes-death-ray) and got some fairly disappointing results.

Comment: `Several such mirrors could make a decent solar collector for cooking purposes` ... the example that you linked does not involve `several mirrors` ... more like `hundreds of mirrors`

Comment: I seriously doubt whether you can pull this off.

Comment: @HotLicks If he uses actual mirrors rather than mirror *paint* it might be possible. There are solar power plant designs that use mirrors to boil water to generate power with turbines, after all.

Comment: Either stick alli foil to cardboard, or splash out on buying polished alli sheet.

Answer (score 16):

I'd consider Mylar film and spray adhesive. Heck, you could probably repurpose some snack bags or party balloons and help save the planet. It can be applied to any shape you like if you cut it into strips.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to use solar heat to cook , I would get polished aluminum . Such reflectors are used for light fixtures. They are light, strong , not affected by water, and will not break when you drop them. I measured one from an aquarium light and it is 0.011" thick. They can also be cleaned better than a painted surface. Most painted surfaces get dirty and become less reflective. In a study of oil storage tanks ( before the net so no reference) ; aluminum paint reflected most heat but got dirty quickly . After a year,  a white high gloss urethane reflected most heat , it did not chalk and dirt tended to wash off of it.  Unfortunately I do not know a source for polished aluminum panels.

Answer (score 5):

Use the mylar film.

Make a frame on a board and glue the edge of the mylar film around the frame.

Make a hole and fit an air valve - all this has to be airtight.

Pump up the mylar film to form a parabola and then cover it with resin and fibre. A couple of layers should do.

Once hard you can cut around the edge and you have a very reflective and light mirror for your solar grill / cooker.

Comment: Note that the shape you get by applying air pressure/vacuum to a uniform sheet covering a circular opening is a spherical cap, not a parabola. A spherical cap will never focus into a single point, always onto the entire axis.

Comment: Will the metal coating on the mylar get messed up as the mylar stretches?

Answer (score 3):

No Paint at all.

Spray adhesive and aluminum foil.

Or aluminum foil duct tape, but the former will (almost certainly) cost less, comes in larger sheets, and can be made smoother if the substrate is smooth.

Alternatively, aluminum flashing (natural/unpainted) for a more robust hunk of fairly shiny metal that can support itself between some lightweight ribs to guide its shape. Polish it more if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Mylar film and basically anything reflective would work. If your talking about paint though, the most reflective paints that I know about are silver and/or chrome paint. I'm pretty sure that both of those paints can be used to paint on cardboard and plastic.